# Process com.Android.app(pid ***) has died

Tags: android

I am facing a very device specific issue here and trying to understand what this error means.
Only On HTC One X running 4.0.3.

Consider this - 1) Login Screen, 2) Home/Menu Screen, 3) Detail Screen (have phone number on it).

When user is on 3rd screen of my app (i.e. he has loged in, selected one option from menu screen and from Detail screen he select to dial a phone number. Dialer gets open he do the call and ends it. Now when he presses back button and lands back to detail screen of my app. The cached data which based on his login information is gone.

Logs show me this - as soon as user press the end button, I see in log that "Process com.****.*** (pid***) has died.

So from my understanding OS is killing my app. 
1) Why?
2) What does "Process died " means. (Only cached data is getting deleted previous activities are still in stack with no data.)

Comment: Do you have a full crash log?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I don't want to post all of it here.

Comment: Then you're on your own with this one. Good luck.

Comment: I see, but at least someone can answer me my 2 question. 2) What does "Process has died" means.